# How do moving colliding particles create heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, atoms, air

I have a question?
If moving colliding particles create heat then how come the cold wind is not hot but it has moving particals? Why and how do moving particles create heat? Just curios.

Thank You for your answers.

Comment: So, is it cold one summer day with no winds?